# Keyboard is being dismissed on outside touch and onPress() is not working for the first time

Tags: react-native, keyboard, react-native-calendars

I am using **Agenda** from **wix/react-native-calendars**. In my container, I have one button,on click of which opens Modal and one TextInput from native-paper. When I click the button when keyboard is opened onPress() of button is not working but when I press button for the second time, it is working properly and also keyboard is being dismissed on outside touch.How to make the button's onPress() to work on first click?

```
import React, { useEffect,useState, useRef } from 'react'
import {
    StyleSheet, Modal, Pressable,
    TouchableOpacity, Keyboard, Text, View
} from 'react-native'
import { Calendar, CalendarList, Agenda } from 'react-native-calendars';
import { useIsFocused } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { TextInput, RadioButton } from 'react-native-paper';

                 <View
                    style={
                        {
                            justifyContent: 'center',
                            alignItems: 'center',
                            padding: 10,
                            marginRight: 10,
                            marginTop: 17,
                            backgroundColor: 'white',
                            borderRadius: 10,
                            shadowColor: "#000",
                            shadowOffset: {
                                width: 0,
                                height: 6,
                            },
                            shadowOpacity: 0.39,
                            shadowRadius: 8.30,

                            elevation: 13,
                        }
                    }>

                    <TouchableOpacity

                        style={{
                            padding: 8,
                            backgroundColor: 'orange',
                            borderRadius: 5,
                            marginBottom: 10
                        }}
                        onPress={() => dayClicked(item)}>

                        <Text style={{ padding: 3, }}>
                            Add Event to this date
                    </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <Text
                        style={{
                            color: 'brown'
                        }}>{item.name}</Text>
                    <Text
                        style={{
                            marginTop: 20,
                            color: 'brown'
                        }}>{item.name1}</Text>

                    <TextInput
                        value={eventName}
                        onChangeText={(value) => setEventName(value)}
                        style={{ marginTop: 30, width: '100%' }}
                        label="Name of the event"
                        placeholder="Enter name of the event"
                        returnKeyType="done"

                    />

                </View>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should encapsulate the data in scrollview and use this property.

```
<View>
      <ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'>
      ...
      </ScrollView>
</View>
```

Comment: Thanks @ankit for the answer. I have changed the code and wrapped it with Scrollview but it's still not working.

Comment: @StackOverflowAsker Is this component being wrapped in another parent scrollview component?

Comment: That component is in react-native-calendars Agenda renderitem.